# Enqueue jquery-ui elements in Wordpress theme option page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Well, I know this is a commonly asked question, but almost all of them like '2 or 3 years ago'. Since Wordpress had some serious core changes recently, thought it'd be better to get an updated answer.

What I wanted to do is add this jquery slider to my wordpress custom admin page.

[image]

In today's Wordpress, is **jquery-ui** coming in built ? or I do need to include it using `wp_enqueue_script` or I should use some external url CDN?

Since I'm working on Wordpress 4.2, could you please tell me the proper way of adding this functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: When you enqueue your custom script in the wordpress, you can add a dependency - check [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress). Basically you'd have something like: `wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-slider'), '1.0.0', true );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the wordpress allows you to add multiple dependencies. You can check the details on the [wp_enqueue_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress) page in the documentation.

What you'd do is add a dependency to your script where you initialize your slider. In your `functions.php` where you enqueue your scripts add this

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-slider'), '1.0.0', true );
```

`example.js` is the script file where you initialize your slider. It depends explicitly on `jquery` and on `jquery-ui-slider`, so you know that the slider will work with the slider ui component of the jquery-ui.

It's split into parts so that you don't have to enque entire `jquery-ui` which is quite heavy on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the info... Will do as you said :)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery-ui actually ships with WordPress. So since you are working in WordPress, this is how you should add jquery ui ( the slider ) to your application.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'your-script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/your-js-app.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-slider'), '1.0.0', true );
```

1) `your-script-name` is the name of your script.

2) get_template_directory_uri()  gets the url to your theme. If you are using the above code in a plugin then use  plugin_dir_url( **FILE** ).

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url

3) array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-slider') is the list of dependencies that your js app requires. In this case it needs `jquery` and `jquery-ui-slider`.

4) `1.0.0` is the version of your js application.

5) `true` means you are outputting your application in the footer of the admin page.

More reference on `wp_enqueue_script` on https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Answer (score 2):

> and at many cases you should use selector : 'jQuery' instead of '$'.

**example:**
`$('#menu')` in wp: `jQuery('#menu')`

Comment: Actually this is the most valuable answer for me.  $ and JQuery symbol mess was the reason my code didn't work... :) Thanks a lot :)