# Wordpress functions.php file not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add all my themes JavaScript files in function.php and my scripts are

```
<script src="http://localhost/xampp/website/nextgen/wp-content/themes/nextgen/nextgen/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

how can i add these to my functions.php i have tried several tutorials but it not work for me.

Show me demo with the above code

Comment: isn't jquery automatically loaded by wordpress?

Comment: It is. You should register your own custom script, and make it dependent on jquery. Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33952347/629127) on how you can load dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Place this in functions.php file:

```
function addthemejs() { 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', 'http://localhost/xampp/website/nextgen/wp-content/themes/nextgen/nextgen/js/jquery.min.js' , array(), "", false );   );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' , 'addthemejs' );
```

I have hardcoded your code, you have to know that is not so good solution, but if you are just testing it's ok I guess